# Laravel vuejs momentjs timezone

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, momentjs

I have a problem. In `app.php` I have a timezone:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
```

In `bootstrap.js` I writed:

```
window.moment = require('moment');

window.moment.locale('ru');
```

In `app.js` I have filter:

```
Vue.filter('relative', value => {
   return moment(value).locale('ru').fromNow();
});
```

When I use this filter and add new comment with vuejs, I get time in future. On my PC timezone is another. On my pc time is: 22:04, but on laravel +1.00 (23:04). How I can use timezone only on server and show relative time of server?

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to get the value from app.php into the JS? Or are you wanting to configure the JS to utilize the timezone correctly? I would also suggest moment-tz instead of just moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import moment as below:

```
const moment = require('moment');
require('moment/locale/ru');
```

This worked for me when i used moment with italian locale